# Draw block diagram of equation

Tags: filter, block-diagram

I'm kind of new to this and was wondering how I would go to draw a block diagram for a differential equation that I've recently calculated?:   y[n] = y[n-1]+ [1/4] ([x[n]-x[n-4]])

There is no problem for me to calculate these types of mathematics, but I do have problems to visualize/sketch it in terms of block diagrams etc, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Draw a block with x[n] as input and y[n] as output and put the formula in the middle of the block. Then evolve it a little deeper. Start simple and sharpen your pencil.

Comment: Draw 4 unit delay blocks in a chain to generate `x[n-4]` and one unit delay block to generate `y[n-1]`. Add them with appropriate gains to get `y[n]`.